# Ler arquivo com formato não ascii [à="<U+00E0>"]

Tags: r, utf-8, unicode

Eu estou lendo um arquivo no R chamado `roubobs.rds`. é um formato proprietário do R e eu não consegui abrir em excel. Eu consigo importar os dados para uma variável mas, dentro dos registros, os textos estão com códigos não ascii (unicode? utf-8?). Ja vasculhei para tentar descobrir que codigo é este, bem como ja tentei exportar como CSV, mas não funciona. Alguem tem uma luz? Preciso que o que aparece como "Assalto  mo armada" apareça como "Assalto à mão armada".

O código do R que está lendo é este aqui:

```
dados <- readRDS("roubo2.rds")
```

O arquivo pode ser baixado aqui: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yp9r0tln0vwdvej/roubo2.rds?dl=0
Estou rodando RStudio em Mac. SessionInfo abaixo.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.12.1 (Sierra)
```

Comment: Eu baixei e consegui ler o arquivo `roubo2.rds` com a acentuação correta, também no Mac. Ou seja, não consegui reproduzir o teu problema. Entretanto, há algumas pequenas diferenças entre os nossos sistemas, como tu pode ver na minha session info: `R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.2`. Seria possível colar tua session info completa para que eu possa comparar com a minha? Por exemplo, a configuração de locale não está disponível na tua, e na minha é `en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: Isto é bem curioso. Supostamente, os arquivos .rds são uma serialização binária da tabela, isto é, mais ou menos uma cópia do estado a tabela na memória no momento em que ela foi salva. Dito isso, não consegui reproduzir seu problema (linux mint 18 aqui).

Comment: Curioso mesmo. Pelo menos duas pessoas tentaram reproduzir o problema e não conseguiram.

Answer (score 2):

Para exportar para .csv no encoding correto é só adicionar o argumento `fileEncoding` na função `write.csv()`

O código ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
dados <- readRDS('roubo2.rds')

write.csv2(dados, 'roubo2.csv', fileEncoding = 'UTF-8')
```

---

Também sugiro que mude as variáveis no formato Factor para Char, já que vc está trabalhando com textos. Para fazer isso é só utilizar o `as.character()`. Exemplo:

```
roubo$tipo <- as.character(roubo$tipo)
```

Quando for ler um arquivo .csv vc pode fazer isso diretamente passando o argumento `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` na função `read.csv()`

---

Para finalizar, seria bom utilizar a versão 3.2 do R, já que a grande maioria dos pacotes são desenvolvidos pra essa versão.